# What's the best way to apply the same rule in multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My application has a dashboard screen which has many charts showing metrics and results of user activity, sales performance, etc.

These results can be filtered by date, user and many other options. Supposing I've got one query for each chart, **what's the best way to apply the same filtering rule in these  multiple queries?**  Whats the best way to replicate the same "where" clause (the same filtering rule) accross many queries?

As example,

> SELECT * FROM users WHERE date = '2014-10-03';
>
> SELECT * FROM products WHERE date = '2014-10-03';

Both queries have same rules.
Some suggested to set a variable with this rule and concatenate it to other queries. Something like:

> $where = "WHERE date = '2014-10-03'";
>
> $query = "SELECT * FROM users ". $where;
>
> ...
>
> $query = "SELECT * FROM products ". $where;
>
> ...

But I can't see this as a good pratice.

Comment: Treat each query as *distinct* operations - don't try to "optimize" this operation across different queries. However, do reuse/cache the results of queries as appropriate (e.g. no need to run the *same* query N times to display in different containers). Employ proper relational design, appropriate indices, updated statistics, and trust the RDBMS to correctly implement a good plan for each *distinct* query - profile the performance if there is a doubt.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What filtering rule?

Comment: Add the same `where` clause to each of the queries.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, but my question reffers to whats the best way to replicate the same "where" clause (the same filtering rule) accross many queries.

Comment: @FelipeFrancisco And my comment-reply was *use three distinct queries*. How they are generated to reduce code duplication (eg.) is a secondary question. I recommend building each query from scratch (the overhead is negligible) following a set of rules and using proper SQL placeholders.

Comment: @user2864740 I do have different queries. Supposing that I have the following queries: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE update_date = '2014-10-03'" and "SELECT * FROM products WHERE update_date = '2014-10-03'". Both queries will have the same where clause.
I'm trying to find the best way to replicate these rules along other queries, because defining a $where variable and concatenating it to each query don't seems to be the proper solution to me :\

Comment: The "query generator" function should apply rules (eg. a simple object describing the filters/etc) to generate the applicable query. However, *rebuild* the SQL distinctly (call the "query generator" multiple times) for the queries  - *and* use placeholders when doing so! Generating the (non-placeholder) WHERE clause once and then using string concatenation goes nowhere fun to maintain. Higher-level ORMs already provide ways to build queries dynamically given a set of rules and/or query generators (eg. it may already be a "solved problem" for this case with a suitable framework).

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks! Unfortunatelly, my company's application don't have a query-builder and we're on the final step of the project. There's no way I can use an ORM Framework at this moment :(.

Using an ORM Framework with a query builder (Laravel, as an example), I would do something like: Users::where('date', '2014-10-03') or Products::where('date', '2014-10-03'). In this case I could foreach($rule as $field => $value) { {Model}::where($field, $value) } to apply the rules dinamically, but I can't see how to do it with a hardcoded SQL string without a query-builder.

Comment: Write your own "query generator" (it needs be naught more than a single method) that cover the rules and the domain of the function. Call it *once* for *each* query generated .. and **use** placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

If it is similar to issue I had in past I guess you need these restricted by many often repetitive WHERE conditions. User, department permission, time, etc.

What worked in my case was making these into string variables and reusing them across queries that produce charts and graphs. Of course, do not insert user data into your dynamic queries. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution is useful (I've done this way too), but is this the suitable solution?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with dynamic queries like this when you watch for sql injection. In big BI products these may be created as filter objects, but under the hood they are doing exactly the same what you already do with concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be a better idea to only keep the value dynamic in case tables do not share the same column name for date.

```
$date = '2014-10-03';

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `date_added` = $date";

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE `date_purchased` = $date";
```

Note: use appropriate validation and security checks for using user input data in sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into using Prepared Statements.  Similar to bind variables in Oracle.

*The query only needs to be parsed (or prepared) once, but can be executed multiple times with the same or different parameters*

Good explanation here: http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Prevents SQL injection attacks as well